# How to use parent div like frame for child div when child is moving out of parent border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate move (up or down) a child div out of the view. But while doing so I want to use the parent as a border so that it disappears as soon as it crosses the parent border. What I mean is:
[image] 
this is my screen
when the child leaves the parent this happens
[image]
but what I want is
[image]
and then the child disappears. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You might try `overflow:hidden`. See [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: @showdev Wow absolutely. Thanks that was quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the parent div

```
overflow: hidden;
```